# SELECT w/ INNER JOIN Query on Optional Columns

Tags: sql-server, join, select

I have five tables: `File2`, `Branches_of_Study`, `Schools`, `Education_Establishments`, and `Certificates`. `File2` is the transaction table with all the other tables as reference tables.

`File2` is all about the educational background of an employee. The employee has to select from a dropdown list in the site the education establishment first, e.g. `Highschool`, `College`, etc. Branch of Study refers to the course the employee has taken, e.g. `IT`, `HRM`, `Photography`, etc.

Upon selecting `College`, the employee must select a `Branch of Study`. But when selecting `Highschool`, selecting a branch of study is not allowed.

I have a gridview in the site that shows all of the employee's educational attainment. Here is my query:

```
SELECT File2.file2_id,
    File2.candidate_id,
    ee.education_establishment,
    s.school,
    File2.school_others,
    File2.start_date,
    File2.end_date,
    bs1.branch_of_study AS branch_of_study_1,
    c.certificate,
    File2.course_appraisal,
    bs2.branch_of_study AS branch_of_study_2
FROM File2
    INNER JOIN Education_Establishments ee
            ON File2.education_establishment_code = ee.education_establishment_code
    INNER JOIN Schools s
            ON File2.school_code = s.school_code
    INNER JOIN Branches_of_Study bs1
            ON File2.branch_of_study_1_code = bs1.branch_of_study_code
    INNER JOIN Branches_of_Study bs2
            ON File2.branch_of_study_2_code = bs2.branch_of_study_code
    INNER JOIN Certificates c
            ON File2.certificate_code = c.certificate_code
 WHERE File2.candidate_id = 100003
```

The query returns only results for the `College` entries for employee number `100003`. I assume this is caused by having `null` values in the `Branch of Study` fields for `Highschool` entries.

I want a query that will show all entries (`College` and `Highschool`) and at the same time showing the text value (not the code) from the reference tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If joining is "optional", then it is not an inner join, by definition.
Consider investigating left joins.

Comment: The joins are required, as I want to display the text values of the references tables and not the codes. It is the columns `branch_of_study_1` and `branch_of_study_2` are optional, and I assume this causes the select query to only return entries in which `branch_of_study_1` and `branch_of_study_2` are `not null`.

Comment: If branch_of_study_1 and branch_of_study_2 are optional (nullable), then File2.branch_of_study_1_code and File2.branch_of_study_2_code are nullable, too. Nulls on any side of an inner join suppress the entire row from the output. Maybe I am missing something. Anyway, I suggest you reduce your problem to a smaller one, having only two tables and one join, for example - right now it may be hiding some relevant details behind unnecessary complexity.

Comment: So I tried `LEFT JOIN` on the columns that are optional, and I can confirm it works. It now returns the `College` entries together with the `Highschool` entries. Thank you!